# EMC storage + powercf command + powerpath

Tags: solaris, storage, cluster

When I run  `powercf -q` on my Solaris machine, what changes does this command do on the EMC storage, or on  Solaris file system?

From manual page:

```
 DESCRIPTION
 During system boot on Solaris  hosts,  the  powercf  utility
 configures  PowerPath  devices by scanning the HBAs for both
 single-ported and multiported storage  system  logical  dev-
 ices.  (A multiported logical device shows up on two or more
 HBAs with the same storage system subsystem/device identity.
 The  identity  comes  from the serial number for the logical
 device.) For each storage system logical device found in the
 scan  of  the HBAs, powercf creates a corresponding emcpower
 device entry in the emcp.conf file, and it saves  a  primary
 path and an alternate primary path to that device.
```

Comment: That man page explains it pretty well. What don't you understand in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any changes on the EMC storage.  It only scans the fibre channel bus to see what world-wide names are visible through each local port.  If it sees the same WWN through multiple ports, then it sets that storage device up for multipath I/O.

Changes are made to emcp.conf in /kernel/drv, and those changes in turn effect how device paths are created under /devices and/or /dev.

If you're on a Solaris system with a zfs root, you can install fresh, snapshot the system, then install PowerPath, run `powercf -q`, and do a `zfs diff rpool/ROOT/solaris@snapshot rpool/ROOT/solaris` to see exactly what changed in your root filesystem.

If you don't have zfs root, you could always install a system, let it sit for 30 minutes, then run `powercf -q`, then use `find / -mmin -30` to find files younger than 30 minutes.